# Getting errors when using move_uploaded_file

Tags: php, forms, file-upload

I'm trying to create a form to upload pictures to my site, But i keep getting the following error:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(../Uploads/c0vraJo.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/Includes/resource.inc.php on line 43

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpDMQ2yr' to '../Uploads/c0vraJo.jpg' in /var/www/html/Includes/resource.inc.php on line 43
object(Resource)#3 (2) { ["_id":"Resource":private]=> string(1) "1" ["_path":"Resource":private]=> string(20) "/Uploads/c0vraJo.jpg" }
```

And the code:

```
$targetDir = "../Uploads/";

$targetFile = $targetDir . basename($_FILES['picture']['name']);
$fileType = pathinfo($targetFile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'], $targetFile);
```

I'm running Ubuntu and I've set the folder permission to 777, the owner is www-data and the group is www-data.

Please let me know if i should supply further information and thanks in advance

Comment: Try using the absolute path

Comment: Akitunde, that worked :D would you happen to know why that would be necessary?